# jsp countdown timmer that can be referesh if we refreshing the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i have a  timer code but it is refreshing  when we refresh the page please  give me a  code that   timer is not refreshing    when we refresh the web page

i want that code for online  examination application i have a  code bt  when i go from one question to another question the timer is   also restart `

```
  var tim;

    var min = 30;
    var sec = 59;
    var f = new Date();

    function f1() {
        f2();
        document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "You started your Exam at " + f.getHours() + ":" + f.getMinutes()+":"+f.getSeconds();


    }
    function f2() {
        if (parseInt(sec) > 0) {
            sec = parseInt(sec) - 1;
            document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time  is :" + min + " Minutes ," + sec + " Seconds";
            tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);

        }
        else {
            if (parseInt(sec) == 0) {
                min = parseInt(min) - 1;
                if (parseInt(min) == 0) {
                    clearTimeout(tim);
                    location.href = "final.jsp";

                }
                else {
                    sec = 60;
                    document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time  is :" + min + " Minutes ," + sec + " Seconds";
                    tim = setTimeout("f2()", 1000);
                }
            }

        }
    }


      </script>
     </head>
    <body onload="f2()" >



            <div id="starttime"></div><br />
              <div id="endtime"></div><br />

            <div id="showtime"></div> 
    </div>
     </form>
   </body>
   </html>`
```

Comment: for an application like this you will need server controlled time, client controlled is just to easy to circumvent

Comment: can u  please sand me  the server controlled timer

Comment: my mail id -  gauravbvu@gmail.com

Comment: no, show us what you have tried and IF you have trouble we will try to help

Comment: i am sanding my code above of the  comment plz find this

Comment: asking for the code with no intention of trying to solve it.